# Silverlight: IsolatedStorageSettings to persist data between page refresh

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am using `IsolatedStorageSettings` class to store some application data that should be retained after page refresh of my Silverlight Navigation Application.
The data is stored in page FirstPage.xaml and is retrieved in SecondPage.xaml.
The following code works just fine if I do not do a refresh. However if I do a refresh on the SecondPage.xaml (second page), the values are returning empty from AppStore. What could be the reason.

```
public static class AppStore
{
    private static IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;      

    public static String MyData
    {
        get 
        {                
            if (appSettings.Contains("MyData"))
            {
               return(appSettings["MyData"].ToString());                   
            }                
            return String.Empty; 
        }
        set 
        {
            if (!appSettings.Contains("MyData"))
            {
                appSettings.Add("MyData", string.Empty);
            }
            appSettings["MyData"] = value;                
        }
    }
}

public partial class FirstPage : Page
{
     private string data = "somevalue";
     .
     .
     public FirstPage()
     {
        AppStore.MyData = data;
     }   
}


public partial class SecondPage : Page
{     
     public SecondPage()
     {
        ContentText.Text = AppStore.MyData;
     }   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not saving the modifications in the IsolatedStorageSettings File,
you should use this

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

Note that you can use IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings instead of a new instance of IsolatedStorageSettings.
also don't save on each modification to your settings, just call this method in your App.Exit() event handler, saving data to the hard disk is time consuming.

Comment: Actually I don't need to save data between different application runs, just need to maintain it between page refreshes. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: When you refresh the pages, the app will exit and reload and the saved data in the managed memory will be lost, you'll need to persist it to the hard disk.